# Education tag and questions on physics education

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

Today, I have seen [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/708549/would-it-be-more-insightful-to-teach-students-lagrangian-hamiltonian-mechanics-b) closed as an *opinion-based* question.

I have read [previous (short) discussions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11236/where-am-i-supposed-ask-questions-regarding-physics-education-research) about the issue of questions on physics education topics in SE (see also [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4244/what-kind-of-education-questions-should-we-allow)), but I do not see a rational policy about these kind of questions.

First of all, we should consider the existence of a tag *education* whose description is: *How is physics taught and learned. Teaching strategies, class examples, and demonstrations; learning resources, career advice, etc.*
Why is there a tag like this if any question related to it would be classified as *opinion-based*? At least, it seems to me there is a contradiction between the existence of such a tag and the way some users (and moderators) interpret the site policy.

However, I want to get to the heart of the issue, which is the relationship between physics education research and [PSE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour). The description of PSE on the main Stack Exchange page is

> Physics
> Q&A for active researchers, academics, and students of physics

I have difficulty understanding why a question relevant to physics teachers (academics) cannot be formulated on PSE. Taking also into account that there is no specific site for physics education questions (like is the case for mathematics education questions).

In another [discussion about the same issue](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/pedagogical-questions-about-physics), the suggestion was to create a specific site. That could be fine. However, I think that before the process of creation of a specific site goes on, questions about physics education could be hosted in PSE. If I am not wrong, something like that was done in the past for questions about astronomy.

Of course, the form of the question is important. However, I disagree that every question about physics education automatically triggers *opinion-based answers*. [Physics education research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physics_education_research) is a well-established field of specialization for physicists, and there is well-established scientific literature containing scientific results, not just opinions. I think that questions and answers remaining inside the perimeter of rationally justified arguments should have the right to appear in PSE. If the majority of the community has a different idea, it should be explicitly stated, and, in that case, I would suggest eliminating the *education* tag.

Comment: Two general remarks, which are not specific to education: 1. The (non-)existence of a tag is not an argument for on- or off-topicness of a certain subject either way: All users with more than 1k reputation can create new tags, and there isn't really any way to delete them except to untag all questions tagged with them or call in support from SE (which we only do when a tag is considered actively detrimental, which is rare).

Comment: 2. It is *not* the case that astronomy.SE was created in order to allow physics.SE to make astronomy questions off-topic - in fact, many astronomy questions are still on-topic here (see [this discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13227/50583), and [this discussion](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8930/50583) for similar issues with hsm.SE). That is, there is *no precedent* for an attitude of "we should allow questions pertaining to X here as long as there's no specific site for it", even if looking at today's sets of SE sites might lead one to assume that.